# Behaviour of toolbar.addElement in java5 and java7

Tags: java, extjs, java-7, java-5

I wanted to know is there any difference in behavior of `toolbar.addElement` in Java5 and Java7..
We have migrated our java version from 5 to 7 and entire application code is same.

Still template is not being added on same menu bar as in when used java5.

I have  searched about it on Google but did not find anything relevant information.please give your views on the same.

Comment: Of which class exactly is `toolbar`? For example, the `javax.swing.JToolBar` does not have an `addElement` method.

Comment: toolbar is the variable defined..code snippet

Comment: You are talking about a javaScript library class behaving differently after migrating your server's java version? As the two things are not directly related you have to provide more information and also do more research on your own.